# SQL Server Reporting Services 2005 Licensing

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, licensing

Does the use of subscriptions in Reporting Services 2005 require special licensing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subscriptions (via email) is included in SSRS for free, however each client viewing the report has to have a SQL cal unless you have the CPU version.  If you're only going to serve up reports via HTML (webpage) where tracking the number of users is nearly impossible, then a CPU license is required for reporting.

[Here is Microsoft's licensing scheme for SSRS](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/Special-Considerations.aspx)