# SQL Server Reporting Services Pricing

Tags: .net, sql, reporting-services, reporting, service

I am trying to understand the pricing requirements for a client to deploy reporting services reports to the web.  Do they have to buy any sort of special Report Server license in order to deploy reports, or is that included in the standard versions of SQL 2005?

Comment: [This is a duplicate and your answer is here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467717/sql-server-reporting-services-2005-licensing)

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure that Reporting Services 2005 is included with a standard SQL Server 2005 license. The same can be said for Analysis and Integration Services.

Comment: Note that report server is not included by default with Express Edition, and report builder is not available with Express Edition at all.

Comment: The "SQL Server 2005 Express with Advanced Tools" has the SSRS. He may not need the report builder. I have never used the report builder.

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with MS Licensing but I am assuming it's minimal, if not free at all. I am assuming that because the [MS SQL Server 2005 Express with Advanced Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=5b5528b9-13e1-4db9-a3fc-82116d598c3d&displaylang=en) has SSRS in it. I can build a Reporting Server system for free using the [MS SQL Server 2005 Express edition with the Advanced Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=5b5528b9-13e1-4db9-a3fc-82116d598c3d&displaylang=en).